# PHP passing command line options

Tags: php, command-prompt

How could I pass multiple options through -d to PHP using the command line while running a script ?

```
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
```

For example, I want to display errors as well as set the memory limit, however,

```
php -d display_errors=1 memory_limit=-1 index.php
```

does not work and throws an error

Answer (score 1):

One option = one -d

```
php -d display_errors=1 -d memory_limit=-1  index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`php -dmemory_limit=5G index.php`
You can run in this way.